# Using custom ChangeExecListener in Liquibase 4.2.2

Tags: java, liquibase

We are trying to upgrade the Liquibase version we use in our Java project at work, but whenever we run an update we get an exception telling us "ChangeExecListener already defined".

We've been using a custom ChangeExecListener to do some logging to our gui. We set the listener using `liquibase.setChangeExecListener(new LiquibaseChangeExecListener(logger));`. Looking at the code and the documentation, it seems that only the `HubChangeExecListener` from Liquibase can be used now, which is not configurable as far as I can tell. I have found no issues in the Github repo or other questions discussing this, so it seems this is not a common way to do things.

Is this use case actually not supported anymore or am I missing something?

Comment: I would recommend asking this question either on the liquibase forum: https://forum.liquibase.org or in our #developer channel on Discord: https://discord.gg/9yBwMtj as there are more peers  there that specifically are familiar with the internals.

Comment: Thanks, I was debating posting this here or on the forum. Guess I'll try over there as well.

Comment: Actually, having almost sent off my forum post, I decided to check if anything had happened in the Github repo during my absence. There now exists a issue relating to this exact problem. I'll add it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my absence over the last few weeks, an issue about this exact topic was created in the Github repo. I'd recommend checking out the progress there if someone runs into the same problem.

Link to issue: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1651